# Issues in python executing cursor

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

Hello I doing a web app in django using Visual studio 2013 like ide, team foundation for code management and postgres for database, I have install all the requirement that I need in python 2.7 64bits...

I have this code, for some reason don't run what is in the for, everything is correct because I try the query in postgres and shows me data and this happend to me everytime I do a new function in postgres but like magic suddenly randomly start working and I don't know the reason of this issue... would be great if anyone has experience with this issue  tell me why happens

```
call_proccess_students="SELECT * FROM process_monitoreo_doc_det(19,"+paramdep+","+parammun+","+paramesc+",'"+paramturn+"','"+paramdate+"')"    
cursor.execute("BEGIN")
cursor.execute(call_proccess_students)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    matches_students.append(dict(label=row[0],rulesetvalue=row[1]))
ausen_students = dict(students=matches_students)
cursor.execute("COMMIT")
cursor.close()
results.update(ausen_students)

return build_json_response(results)
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the new function was created by a colleague and I download from TF

Comment: the function is in the migration and I generate it with django sync

Comment: Good thing it didn't work. This is the wrong way! If you are using django you don't need to do any of this. You can fetch objects by just doing MyModel.objects.filter() or MyModel.objects.all(), easily escape it into json and wrap it around a transaction with just one statement.

Comment: thanks that work too